# Iterating Regression ML model by group

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with hundred thousands of rows and grouped by each county in US. I have my model working trained and tested with nationwide data but I want to test and see running model by county would improve accuracy or not, So;

I want to run Decision Tree Regression by each county, so need to train_test_split each group and then run DTR for each group however I could not split my data by group and do not know how to run DTR by each group.

I am also not sure if i need to run by group since i know DTR sees county names as categorical data so learning based on it, still want to test running by county grouping.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
  'y': np.random.randn(20),
  'a': np.random.randn(20), 
  'b': np.random.randn(20),
  'color': ['alf', 'bet', 'sar', 'tep'] * 5,
  'county': ['a', 'b'] * 10})

df3.head()


X = df3.drop('y', axis=1)
y = df3.y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=10, max_features='auto', min_samples_leaf=5,
                      min_samples_split=5, random_state=42)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
regressor.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with simply looping through the counties and splitting the data according to that?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
regressors = {}
for county in set(X['county']):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X[X['county']==county][['a','b']], 
            y[X['county']==county], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=10, max_features='auto', min_samples_leaf=5,
                          min_samples_split=5, random_state=42)
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(regressor.score(X_test, y_test),end='\n\n')
    regressors[county] = regressor
```

As to whether or not this is appropriate for your data I cannot answer. It depends on your implementation and how you want to incorporate information into your model.

Comment: Hmm, how? It ran perfectly fine on my machine. Did you just copy and paste this at the right location?